# Running the Random method 'choices' for an unknown number of iterations

Tags: python, random, probability

Consider the following code

```
import random
fruits = [0, 0]
for _ in range(1000):
    if random.choices(['apple', 'orange'], weights=[0.5, 0.5])[0] == 'apple':
        fruits[0] += 1
    else:
        fruits[1] += 1
```

Looks pretty standard, predictable "output" in the list fruits. But what if you instead let it run for an unknown period of time, face-offs on top of each other, and certain criterion must be met.

```
def game():
    pts_apple = 0
    pts_orange = 0
    while True:
        if random.choices(['apple', 'orange'], weights=[0.54, 0.46])[0] == 'apple':
            pts_apple += 1
        else:
            pts_orange += 1

        if pts_apple >= 5 and pts_apple - pts_orange >= 3: # change for bigger differences
            pts_apple = 0
            pts_orange = 0
            fruits[0] += 1
            break
        elif pts_orange >= 5 and pts_orange - pts_apple >= 3:
            pts_apple = 0
            pts_orange = 0
            fruits[1] += 1
            break
```

What I've noticed is the disparity is more prominent when the criterion for minimum number of points increases, and the when the difference between them must be greater. So, what is going on? I have though about this for quite som time, but I'm stumped. Why would the probability of a winner change so radically? I can only think of one reason

There is som kind of "stacking" going on. So, you win one, but then you must win another, then yet another and so on, until you meet the criteria. Because 'apple' has greater odds, there is a greater chance for 'apple' to win.

Am I missing something?

Also, how would you go about minimizing the disparity, if you have to use certain numbers? **You want to be able to find the probability before you do the computation**, but you don't know the number of 'face-offs'! For example, if you stack them, two 'face-offs' has 'apple' at a two-win probability of .54 * .54, right? But what if there are 200 'face-offs' before you find a winner? Do you use a normal distribution?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you've provided simulates a simple game where players can choose to play as either an "apple" or an "orange". In each round of the game, a player wins a point if they choose the fruit that is chosen by the random.choices function. The game continues until one player has scored at least five points and has at least a three-point lead over the other player. When this happens, the winning player's score is added to the fruits list and the game resets.

The key difference between the first code snippet and the game() function is that the first code snippet simply counts how many times an "apple" or an "orange" is chosen by the random.choices function, while the game() function simulates a game where players can win and lose points. This means that the output of the game() function will be different from the output of the first code snippet.

One thing to note is that the game() function has a potential for an infinite loop, because it does not have any conditions for ending the game if it goes on for too long. This could potentially cause problems if the function is allowed to run for a very long time. It might be a good idea to add a maximum number of rounds or a timeout to the game to prevent this from happening.